# Рефакторинг XAML-разметки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, рефакторинг

Читаю Роберта Мартина и пытаюсь постичь все тонкости рефакторинга.

Если с C#-кодом все более-менее понятно и код мало-помалу начинает радовать глаз, то с XAML всё печально. Разметка громоздкая и трудночитаемая.
Понятно, что многое связано с xml-"наследственностью". Xml избыточен и не очень приятен для глаз, но всё же. Какие есть способы и кто что применяет для рефакторинга xaml?

В идеале хотелось бы избавиться от десятиуровневой иерархии и получить короткие "методы" по 5-7 строчек (как это у меня сделано в c#-коде).

Привожу разметку одного из окон моего последнего WPF-приложения (все 320 строчек "фарша"):

```
<Window x:Class="InfoReceiverB.Views.EditorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InfoReceiverB.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Менеджер скриптов" Icon="/papers2.ico"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="700" Width="1100">

    <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListBox Padding="2.5" Margin="3"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Repo.Queries}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuery}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="0,3,3,3">
                        <Button Content="+"
                                Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                Command="{Binding AddQueryCommand}"/>

                        <Button Content="-"
                                Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                Command="{Binding DelQueryCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedQuery}">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="DarkGray" Margin="3,0"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding SelectedQuery}">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"
                               Padding="5" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>

                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                             Text="{Binding Caption}"
                             Padding="5" Margin="0,3,3,3"
                             AcceptsReturn="True"/>

                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Text="{Binding Body}" 
                             FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="14"
                             Padding="5" Margin="3,0,3,3"
                             AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"
                             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="3"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Background="DarkGray" Margin="0,3"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListBox Padding="2.5" Margin="3"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Repo.QueryPacks}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQueryPack}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="0,3,3,3">
                        <Button Content="+"
                                Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                Command="{Binding AddQueryPackCommand}"/>

                        <Button Content="-"
                                Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                Command="{Binding DelQueryPackCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedQueryPack}">
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Button">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="3"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              Background="DarkGray" Margin="3,0"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{Binding SelectedQueryPack}">
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"
                                   Padding="5" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                                 Text="{Binding Caption}"
                                 Padding="5" Margin="0,3,3,3"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ListBox Name="list1" Padding="2.5" Margin="3"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Repo.Queries,
                                                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="0,3" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button Content="&gt;"
                                    Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.AddQueryToPackCommand,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list1}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Content="&lt;"
                                    Padding="5" Margin="0,7,0,3"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DelQueryFromPackCommand,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list2}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Content="^"
                                    Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.UpQueryInPackCommand,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list2}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>

                            <Button Content="v"
                                    Padding="5" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.DownQueryInPackCommand,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list2}">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="CommandParameter" Value="{x:Null}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Name="list2"
                                 Padding="2.5" Margin="3"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Queries}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid>                    
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                     Rows="1">
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Применить" IsDefault="True"
                    Padding="5" Margin="0,3,3,3"
                    Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}"
                    Click="ApplyButtonClick"/>

            <Button Grid.Column="2"
                    Content="Отмена" IsCancel="True"
                    Padding="5" Margin="0,3,3,3"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Буду рад любым рекомендациям и замечаниям, особенно с примерами

Comment: Красотаааа. Но я бы дополнительно все `Padding`-`Margin`-мусор вынес бы в ресурсники.

Comment: 1. Отказаться от XAML и делать разметку на C#. 2. Отказаться от WPF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, альтернатива WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычной альтернативой является вынесение общих логических частей в отдельный код.

Если у вас есть части разметки с самостоятельным смыслом, самостоятельной функциональностью, их следует вынести в отдельный `UserControl`. Если к тому же куски и повторяющиеся — вы сможете повторно использовать ваш `UserControl`. (Но и без этого, если есть самостоятельный смысл, нужно отделять в новый контрол — как и с процедурами.) Если части повторяются, но не в точности, сделайте ваш `UserControl` *параметризируемым*, чтобы настраивать его вид и поведение. Это полный аналог использования подпрограмм (функций/процедур) в императивном программировании. Без `UserControl`'ов ваш код превращается в неподдерживаемый монолит, точно так же как императивный код без использования процедур.

Далее, если у ваших контролов есть общие свойства, вынесите их в стиль. Это может быть немного сложнее, чем просто писать свойства во всех контролах, но правильно написанный стиль можно повторно использовать, а также наследовать и изменять его. Вы можете заводить иерархии стилей и применять их к вашим контролам, чтобы модифицировать их поведение одинаковым образом. Это аналог АОП в императивном программировании.

P. S.: Это не даст вам 10-строчные части, т. к. XML всё же достаточно многословен, и не допускает многочисленные сущности в одном файле. Думаю, реалистической целью может быть 30-50 строк на файл.