# Как узнать выбраный элемент ComboBox`a в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

Добрый день. Подскажите, как в ListView у ComboBox узнать индекс выбранного элемента? Или если есть альтернативный вариант, как узнать выбранный элемент, прошу, поделитесь

У меня получается так (XAML):

```
<ListView Name="lvServerList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Status" >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="100">
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Новый</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Ожидает</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Обработка</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Отклонен</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">К оплате</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Оплачен</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Раскрой</Label>
                                <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center">Готов</Label>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Ip Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IpAddress}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Код С#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ServerListItem item = new ServerListItem
            {
                Name = "Sample Server",
                IpAddress = "sample-server.com"
            };
            lvServerList.Items.Add(item);
        }        
    }

    public class ServerListItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Использование связывание, завести свойство для выбранного элемента и для всей коллекции.

Comment: Кто минусует? Вопрос-то хороший!

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны действовать через привязку.

Давайте добавим Enum для возможных состояний:

```
enum Status
{
    New,
    Waiting,
    Processing,
    ...
}
```

В ServerListItem добавим свойство для указания типа:

```
class ServerListItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

По идее ваш ServerListItem должен реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged, но мы пока это опустим, сейчас это не принципиально.

Хорошо, теперь мы можем сделать нормальную привязку к SelectedItem:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"
              ItemsSource="..."/>
</DataTemplate>
```

остается как-то получить список всех значений Enum чтобы привязать их в ItemsSource. Я предлагаю сделать для этого небольшое расширение разметки:

```
class EnumExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public EnumExtension() { }

    public EnumExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
}
```

Воспользуемся им:

```
ItemsSource="{local:Enum EnumType=local:Status}"
```

или, благодаря наличию конструктора с параметром, еще короче:

```
ItemsSource="{local:Enum local:Status}"
```

Это уже работает, но в выпадающем списке выводятся строки New, Waiting, и т.д., т.е. просто по имени константы Enum.

Чтобы исправить это можно добавить атрибут `Description` к каждой константе, но, я считаю, это не совсем правильно, т.к. это задача представления, ну и не прокатит, например, при разработке мультиязычного приложения.

Поэтому мы добавим конвертер.

---

У меня есть такая заготовка для удобной реализации конвертеров:

```
abstract class ConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

Воспользуемся ею:

```
class EnumToDescriptionConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public Dictionary<ValueType, string> Dict { get; set; }

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is ValueType v ? Dict[v] : null;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Dict.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value == (string)value).Key;
    }
}
```

В этот конвертер через свойство можно внедрить нужный словарь, например, в зависимости от текущего языка

Ну и немного модифицируем EnumExtension, чтобы также использовался конвертер:

```
class EnumExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

    public Type EnumType { get; set; }

    public EnumExtension() { }

    public EnumExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        EnumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => Enum.GetValues(EnumType).Cast<ValueType>()
               .Select(t => Converter.Convert(t, EnumType, null, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture));
}
```

Ну и где-то надо теперь завести словарь, который будет сопоставлять каждое значение вашего Enum со строковым описанием, я для теста сделал так:

```
class MyDict : MarkupExtension
{
    Dictionary<ValueType, string> dict = new Dictionary<ValueType, string>
    {
        [Status.New] = "Новый",
        [Status.Waiting] = "Ожидает",
        [Status.Processing] = "Обработка",
        ...
    };

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => dict;
}
```

а у вас он может, например, загружаться из ресурсов.

Окончательная разметка:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Status, Converter={local:EnumToDescriptionConverter Dict={local:MyDict}}}"
              ItemsSource="{local:Enum local:Status, Converter={local:EnumToDescriptionConverter Dict={local:MyDict}}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Вместо `EnumExtension` можно использовать `ObjectDataProvider` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145888/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-control-in-wpf

Comment: @FoggyFinder, да, я видел этот топик, но как по мне он более громоздкий и неуклюжий

Comment: @FoggyFinder, кстати, чтобы прикрутить там русскоязычные строчки или мультиязычный интерфейс сделать придется писать такие же конвертеры как в этом ответе.

Comment: Но я предпочитаю сделать пяток мелких классов на шарпе, чем потом мучиться с многоуровневым XAML, который гораздо хуже поддается рефакторингу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667715/Рефакторинг-xaml-разметки

Comment: так и есть, мне понравился вариант с  `ObjectDataProvider`, поэтому решил упомянуть о нем в комментариях

Comment: @FoggyFinder, более того, его, возможно, стоило бы перевести и оформить в виде отдельного ответа

Comment: вы написали отличный ответ, пусть будет комментарием =)