# Проблемы с конвертором

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Проблема в том что конвертер не хочет роботать в **ResourceDictionary(ListBox.xaml)** если он подключен в **App.xaml**,только если на прямую его подключить  в **ListBox.xaml**  **<converters:BoolToStringConverter   x:Key="BoolToString" />** все будет ок.

**Ошибка**:Exception: Cannot find resource named 'BoolToString'.Resource names are case sensitive.(То есть ненаход BoolToString но видит при подключении все конвертори).

**Что я собственно хочу получить**:Можно как-то конвертер получить из **App.xaml** в **ListBox.xaml**
просто не вариат использовать только в **ListBox.xaml**.

**ListBox.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PriceCreator.Services.Converters"
                    >
    <converters:BoolToStringConverter   x:Key="BoolToString" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="VideoListItems" TargetType="ListBoxItem">

        <Grid>
            <Border   
                Name="brd"
                Margin="10,2"
                Background="{StaticResource MediumBrush}"
                CornerRadius="2">
                <Grid  >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="22*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="26*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="818*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Name"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{StaticResource BaseText}" FontSize="18"
                           Margin="5" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  Text="{Binding  Name,StringFormat=Имя товара:{0}}" TextAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="142*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="38*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="229*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="365*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock    Margin="2" x:Name="Price"  Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Price,StringFormat=Цена:{0}}"   FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{StaticResource BaseText}" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <TextBlock    Margin="2" x:Name="CurrencyId" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding CurrencyId}"   FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{StaticResource BaseText}" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock    FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{StaticResource BaseText}"  Margin="2" x:Name="Stock_quantity" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding Stock_quantity,StringFormat=Количество товаров:{0}}" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                        <TextBlock    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray"   Style="{StaticResource BaseText}"  Margin="2" x:Name="Vendor" Grid.Column="3"  Text="{Binding Vendor,StringFormat=Производитель товара:{0}}"     FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="251*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="523*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BaseText}" Margin="2" Text="{Binding Available,StringFormat=Есть товар в наличии:{0},Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"  Foreground="Gray"  />
                    </Grid>


                </Grid>
            </Border>

            <!--<Polygon
                Name="triangle"
                Margin="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Fill="{Binding ElementName=brd, Path=Background}"
                Points="0,0 20,15, 0,30"
                Visibility="Hidden" />-->
        </Grid>


        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBlue}" />
                <!--<Setter TargetName="triangle" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />-->
                <Setter TargetName="Name" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Price" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="CurrencyId" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Vendor" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Stock_quantity" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <!--<Setter TargetName="Id" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />-->
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushBlue}" />
                <Setter TargetName="Name" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Price" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="CurrencyId" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Vendor" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter TargetName="Stock_quantity" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <!--<Setter TargetName="Id" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />-->
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="PriceCreator.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:PriceCreator.Services.Converters"
             StartupUri="Views\PriceCeatorView.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--Подключение ресурсов-->
        <ResourceDictionary >
         <!--Подключение конвертеров-->
         <converters:StringTointConverter x:Key="StringToint" />
         <converters:IntToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IntToVisibility" />
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Colors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Fonts.xaml"/>
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Icons.xaml" />-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\ScrollViewer.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Texts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\Buttons.xaml" />
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\RadioButton.xaml" />-->
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\ContentControls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\UserControl.xaml" />-->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\ListBox.xaml" />

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Знаете что я вам советую... Используйте `MarkupExtension` и не надо будет захламлять ресурсы лишним, ибо достаточно будет указать напрямую нужный конвертор (`<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Text, Converter= {conv:MyExtension}}"/>`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  вы об этом     [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/140876/) `WPF MarkupExtension, использование строк с несколькими ресурсами`?

Comment: Именно. Тут помниться АндейNOP делал как то некий базовый класс, от которого потом удобно наследовать любой конвертор и переопределив всего один `Convert` получить в итоге готовый конвертор в виде расширения разметки.  Можете глянуть [его ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A218063+MarkupExtension) на эту тему, а сам базовый класс можно взять например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/748699/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо вам все шикарно работает, зачем нужен  **ProvideValue**,не пойму  зачем **MarkupExtension** какая его тут функция??

Comment: Если просто, то это некий провайдер источника данных. То есть вам нужно допустим привязаться на уровень выше (такое бывает, если объект находится в коллекции, а его надо привязать к свойству, которое за пределами коллекции), обычно это пишется так: `{Binding Value, elativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}`, а можно [сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746587/220553) расширение разметки, которое будет использоваться как `{ex:Convert DataContext.Value}`. Вот допустим другой вариант, [привязка Enum](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726828/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я понял о чем вы место подниматься по дереву xaml до Window для получения данных в xaml  разметке,мы делаем это программно то есть с# коде? Cпасибо вам что помогли))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключение конвертера `xmlns:converters="clrnamespace:PriceCreator.Services.Converters"`-у меня в папке Services есть  папка Converters.

Базовый класс для создания конвертеров:

```
 abstract class ConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
 {
            public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
            public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)=> throw new NotImplementedException();
            public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
 }
```

Пример конвертер С Bool в String:

```
class BoolToStringConverter : ConverterBase
{
      
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool v = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
            return v ? "Да" : "Нет";
        }
}
```

Пример использования тип данных являться Bool(Available).

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Available"  Margin="2"  Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BaseText}"  Text="{Binding Available,StringFormat=Есть товар в наличии:{0},Converter={converters:BoolToStringConverter}}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"  Foreground="Gray"  />
```