# UWP. Не возникает событие TextChanged при вводе в текстовое поле

Tags: c#, uwp

В приложении UWP в ListView вставлены CheckBox и TextBox. К первому привязан обработчик события Click, ко второму TextChanged. В обработчиках событий вызывается пересчет суммы значений, введенных в TextBox. Проблема в том, что событие TextChanged при изменении TextBox не возникает. Тогда как Click при изменении Checkbox возникает корректно. Не понимаю как такое может быть? И как решить эту проблему?
XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvClientCheckList" IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
              BorderBrush="CornflowerBlue" BorderThickness="2" Height="456">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="12"/>
                <TextBlock Width="70" Text="Код"/>
                <TextBlock Width="320" Text="Операция сервисного обслуживания"/>
                <TextBlock Width="400" Text="Примечания"/>
                <TextBlock Width="104" Text="Цена"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:CheckListItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="70" Text="{x:Bind Code, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <CheckBox Name="cbClientCheckListIsChecked" Width="320" IsChecked="{x:Bind IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{x:Bind Name_ServiceOperation, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          Click="CbClientCheckListIsChecked_Click"/>
                <TextBox Width="400" Text="{x:Bind Comments, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <TextBox Name="tbClientCheckLictPrice" HorizontalTextAlignment="Right" Width="104" Text="{x:Bind Price, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                         TextChanged="TbClientCheckLictPrice_TextChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C# определение класса:

```
public class CheckListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged  // Элемент списка работ
{
    // Поля
    private double price;

    // Свойства
    public int Code { get; set; }                   // Код записи
    public int Code_BP { get; set; }                // Код бизнес-процесса
    public int Code_ServiceOperation { get; set; }  // Код операции сервисного обслуживания
    public string Name_ServiceOperation { get; set; }   // Название операции сервисного обслуживания
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }            // Признак того, что операция выбрана для выполнения
    public string Comments { get; set; }            // Примечания по операции
    public double Price                             // Цена услуги
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Price"); }
    }               

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

С# обработчики событий:

```
private void CbClientCheckListIsChecked_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CalculateCheckList();
    Bindings.Update();
}

private void TbClientCheckLictPrice_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CalculateCheckList();
    Bindings.Update();
}
```

Comment: Почему не реализовать нужную логику в VM?

Comment: @Андрей NOP Приложение писалось ранее без использования VM. Сейчас добавляется новый функционал. Поэтому переписывать весь код под VM нецелесообразно. И не пойму чем тут поможет VM? Проблема с тем, что по какой-то причине не возникает событие при изменении текста в текстовом поле. Оно просто не вызывается. Почему так происходит и как обойти этот глюк?

Comment: Вопрос насчет VM. У меня приложение одностраничное. Навигация осуществляется с использованием Pivot. Соответственно, весь XAML написан в одном файле (около 15000 строк). И я не совсем понимаю как разделить такой XAML на отдельные файлы для реализации паттерна MVVM. Подскажите как?

Comment: Рефакторинг XAML: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716468/218063

Comment: Почему не вызывается событие? Давайте минимальный самодостаточный пример, чтобы можно было вставить в студию и увидеть проблему

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пример чуть позже выложу. В методе CalculateCheckList вставлена строка Debug.WriteLine(sum); которая выводит сумму. Так вот она не срабатывает на событии TextChanged

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пока делал пример, разобрался. Событие TextChanged на самом деле возникает. Но проблема в том, что на момент возникновения этого события данные введенные пользователем ещё не обновились в коллекции. Т. е. обновление данных в привязке срабатывает позже и поэтому расчет неверен. Есть ли какое-либо событие, которое возникает после обновления данных в привязке?

Comment: По UWP не подскажу, ибо не знаю, а в WPF есть Attached-события `Binding.TargetUpdated` и `Binding.SourceUpdated`, одно из них вам подошло бы. Либо, обновлять привязку вручную в обработчике события, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711393/218063

Comment: С другой стороны, если вы пропишете нужную логику в сеттере свойства в VM, то все эти костыли не нужны и всё будет работать как надо сразу.